# Mobile Nav "Back" linking issue

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I'm having an issue with the mobile navigation when using Zurb Foundation framework. In my HTML document the back link is working just fine but when I put the HTML into my CMS (Concrete5) the back link just make the page jump to the top of the page. I'm not getting any JS errors or any leads to fix this issue. Has anyone else ran into this issue? I'm a bit lost at how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a simple HTML button such as:

```
<a href="#" id="history-go-back">back</a>
```

And the appropriate JS:

```
<script>
$('#history-go-back').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return history.back();
});
</script>
```

Should work.

I guess that in your case, the event which is normally attached to your button click is not triggered, so it's acting as a link and going on the top of the page. Maybe you may have missed some JS files in your HTML?

Comment: Foundation's topnav auto put in the back link in the js. it auto adds a <li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="#">Back</a></h5>

Comment: Also, I'm including the js file... <script src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/javascripts/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script> so I'm not for sure why its screwing up.

Comment: maybe you can try debugging inside **foundation.topbar.js**, see around line 144 : `$(this.scope).on('click.fndtn', '.top-bar .has-dropdown .back', function (e)`...  This is a event called when we click the "Back" link. You can try to add some `console.log` there to see if it's triggering fine.

Comment: I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: I put console.log('foo'); in that function and when I click it nothing happens. (I don't see "foo" in console) Thoughts?

Comment: what about a `console.log('hi')` at the beginning of the file? just after `use strict` line, and before `Foundation.libs.topbar`. If not working, include prob. Or maybe foundation isnt called? (`$(document).foundation();` is here right?). -- Im thinking about 3 reasons : 1/ JS not included properly or not called, 2/ another JS of the CMS overriding the event of FoundationJS, or 3/ a FoundationJS bug that I haven't met!

Comment: here is my source... I'm for sure including the files. I'm not seeing any errors at all.http://pastie.org/7820564

Comment: looks like someone else has had the same problem. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/foundation-framework-/Sv2--7eX_To/kaDHbr0OvgsJ will try to implement this.

Comment: I tried to implement this... https://groups.google.com/d/msg/foundation-framework-/Sv2--7eX_To/ZM_AM3r4_L8J but it seems to disable the menu all together.

Comment: console.log('hi'); is firing off just fine where you are saying it needs to go...just after use strict line, and before Foundation.libs.topbar.

Comment: it must be the CMS js because it works fine when I'm logged out.

Comment: ok, then you can try to disable one by one all the non-foundation JS, and see when it works. -- disable all of them first, see if it works ; then enable each JS one by one until it's not working again. Then you got the guilty JS!